# An interesting relation on the set of functions with Lebesgue integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Could you please give an example of functions $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ with the following property:

$$
\forall E>0 \quad \exists \delta>0: \quad \forall x\in [a,b] \quad
\Big( 0<\max\limits_{t\in [a,x]} |f(t)-g(t)|<\delta \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \int\limits_{[a,x]} f(t)g(t)\,dt>E \Big)
$$

Answer (score 1):

How about 
$$f(t) = g(t) = 
\begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{(t-a)^{3/4}} & t \in (a,b] \\
 0 & t=a
\end{cases}
$$